# Vue script loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I am trying to refactor an angular app to Vue in an asp.net mvc app. Following works:

```
<div id="app" style="margin-top:100px;">
{{message}}
</div>

<script>

 const v = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    }
})

</script>
```

However when I move the script to a javascript file it dosent work. I guess its some timing in loading the script. What is best practice here?

Layouts:
I load following in the laysouts file:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script src="~/Scripts/vue.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/main.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Are you loading the script after the div?

Comment: See the [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: But is is normal practice with vue to load it in the loaded event? I havent seen anyone doing this. I guess I just as well could use jquery ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are loading your vue file before the DOM is loaded.  It cannot find your `id="app"` since it hasn't loaded it.

In my projects I have all my html and then load the vue.js file right before the `</body>` end tag.  Like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="app" style="margin-top:100px;">
        {{message}}
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="/myfile.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is best practice to prevent render blocking scripts.  When you put JavaScript in your `<head>` it has to load those file before the `<body>` can start rendering.